# Adjust ps3 eye camera properties - ubuntu

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, camera

I am using OpenCV VideoCapture class to capture video from ps3 eye camera.
the code runs perfect.

But when I change the camera exposure and gain using uvcview and re-run the opencv code I got black images (black frames) and crazy delay.

How can I adjust ps3 eye camera  exposure and gain under ubuntu?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try using the v4l2-ctl tool.

You can see the available controls you can adjust with:

```
v4l2-ctl --list-ctrls
```

and you can adjust what you want using something like:

```
v4l2-ctl --set-ctrl exposure=96
v4l2-ctl --set-ctrl gain=30
```